# Regex to catch strings that are not inside string pattern

Tags: regex

I want to find a regex that catch all strings that are not inside name('stringName') pattern.

For example I have this text:

```
fdlfksj "hello1" dsffsf "hello2\"hi" name("Tod").name('tod') 'hello3'
```

I want my regex to catch the strings:
`"hello1", "hello2\"hi", 'hello3'`  (it should also should catch `"hello2\"hi"` because I want to ignore " escaping).

I want also that my regex will ignore "Tod" because it's inside the pattern name("...")
How should I do it?

Here is my regex that doens't work:

```
((?<!(name\())("[^"]*"|'[^']*'))
```

It doesn't work with ignore escaping: `\"` and `\'`

and it's also not ignore name("Tod")

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<!name\()(["'])[^\)]+?(?<!\\)\1
```

It will match anything other than parenthesis (`[^\)]+?`):

- preceeded by `(["'])` - a quote symbol
- followed by `(?<!\\)\1` - the same quote symbol, which is not preceeded by a slash

In order to avoid getting the values that come after `name(`, there's a condition that checks that `(?<!name\()`.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/z0Scpi/1).

Comment: thanks! it's great but I want to ignore only name(...) not all values between parentheses, how can I do it?

Comment: Just remove that extra check. Updated the answer accordingly. @RoG

Comment: but your answer now catch strings inside name(...).

Comment: can you provide a regex101 link? @RoG

Comment: `(?<=^| )(["']).*?(?<!\\)\1` was very nice.  I want that it will not catch only the strings inside name(...)

Comment: [link](https://regex101.com/r/ErAEQU/1)  I want it will catch the string "hh" inside tye(...)

Comment: is it fine if it matches any string between quotes except when the string is surrounded by "name()" specifically? @RoG https://regex101.com/r/z0Scpi/1

Comment: do you know how can I add to this regex also ignore all strings inside square brackets ["..."] ?

Comment: Sure, it's feasible. Can you update your post with some samples relative to this case? @RoG

Answer (score 0):

```
(["'])((?:\\\1)|[^\1]*?)\1
```

##### Regex Explanation

- `(` Capturing group

  - `["']` Match `"` (double) or `'` (single) quote
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?:` Non-capturing group

    - `\\\1` Match `\` followed by the quote by which it was started
  - `)` Close non-capturing group
  - `|` OR
  - `[^\1]*?` Non-gready match anything except a quote by which it was started
- `)` Close group
- `\1` Match the close quote

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7I7W28/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could get out of the way what you don't want, and use a capture group for what you want to keep.

The matches that you want are in capture group 2.

```
name\((['"]).*?\1\)|('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")
```

**Explanation**

- `name\((['"]).*?\1\)` Match name and then from the opening parenthesis till closing parenthesis between the same type of quote
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` match the single quoted value including matching escapes ones
  - `|`Or
  - `[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` The same for the double quotes
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEVljX/1)